# MySQL - Select * where a substring is before char

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a dictionary database in which every entery looks like this

```
column
word; synonym; synonym | example of usage; example of usage
```

I want to make a select function that will only get the row if it appears in the first part of the data (words and synonyms) and not in the examples of usage (as there are more words there)

I have been trying to do it with REGEXP

```
SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE column REGEXP '[^\|]*word.*\|.*'
```

But for some reason this matches everything in the tables - even where the word doesn't appear at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have everything mashed into a single column, instead of different columns for different parts of the data?

Comment: Use just `'^[^|]*word'` or `'^[^|]*[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]'`.

Comment: Sadly, it's been given to me like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double slashes to escape special characters in MySQL regex. Thus, your `\|` is treated as a `|` and you match every empty space before each "character" in each string.

I suggest just checking if `word` appears before `|` with

```
'^[^|]*word'
```

or - if you need a whole word check:

```
'^[^|]*[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]'
```

The regex matches...

- `^` - start of string
- `[^|]*` - 0 or more characters other than `|`
- `[[:<:]]` - leading word boundary
- `word` - literal sequence of letters
- `[[:>:]]` - trailing word boundary.

Also, this regex is case-insensitive by default. To make it case-sensitive, use `BINARY` keyword.

```
SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE column REGEXP BINARY '^[^|]*[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]'
```

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

You don't have a database.  You have 3 types of information (word, synonym, usage) jammed into one column in one row.

You need a table of word - synonym pairs
You need a table of word - usage pairs
You probably need a word - definition pair table

Do all the parsing *before* inserting the data into the tables.